# Phone number click to call on desktop?

Tags: forms, mobile-web, web, desktop-application, phone-numbers

I'm designing a web flow in which one of the outcomes is to call our support team. On mobile, this is simple enough as pressing on a phone number triggers the alert below.

However, I'm not sure what would be considered the best behaviour for desktop, should I just display the phone number or is there some fanciness whereby we can call from the desktop through Apple's call from a mac thing or through Skype, etc?

[image: Call alert]

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use call links on desktop devices. 
In my case with skype or my VOIP software. I highly appreciate if a company has clickable phone numbers :-)

So just make it a hyperlink.

Some more information: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/click-to-call/

Comment: I find that functionality really annoying, mostly because it messes up the layout of the page when the phone number is highlighted. Might be because I don't really use it. But that can just be turned of, so there is really no reason why you shouldn't make it clickable...

Comment: @anders I think the change in the layout depends on the plugins (e.g. Skype put an Skype icon beside the number. In my case it does not change the layout and is a simple hyperlink and just underlined.